# Strange behaviour of `Stream.take`

Tags: scala, stream

I'm trying some methods of `scala.Stream`, and defined such a method:

```
def my(n: Int) = {
  scala.Stream.from(1).flatMap { i =>
    println("### " + i)
    scala.Stream.from(i).takeWhile(_ < 10).map(j => (i, j))
  }.take(n).filter(x => x._1 < 3 && x._2 < 5).toList
}
```

If I give `n` the number `45`:

```
println(my(45))
```

Which terminates very fast, and prints:

```
### 1
### 2
### 3
### 4
### 5
### 6
### 7
### 8
### 9
List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4))
```

But if the `n` is `46`, it will never ends:

```
### 1
### 2
### 3
### 4
### 5
### 6
...
### 245684
### 245685
### 245686
### 245687
### 245688
### 245689
### 245690
### 245691
...
```

Why it's so strange?

PS: my scala version is `2.11.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 45th entry in the flatmap'ed result is (9,9). This is the last tuple that can be generated from a number i < 10. So to generate a 46th tuple, the code next tries i = 10, but `Stream.from(i).takeWhile(_ < 10)` returns no valid tuples, so the code moves on immediately to i = 11, and so on, giving the printed lines you see, but never generating a new element for the stream...